# Install MySQL stored procedure to database on plugin install in Craft 3

Tags: plugin-development, database, craft3, mysql

I am trying to add a MySQL stored procedure to the database on plugin install in Craft 3.  I currently have an install migration calling a function from the safeUp method. In this function I am using `Craft::$app->getDb()->createCommand(" DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE ...")->execute()`. However this does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: Does the user account Craft is connecting to the database with have [CREATE ROUTINE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-routine) permissions?  Craft doesn't require them by default.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that PostgreSQL has different syntax if you'll be supporting that.

Comment: The user does have Create Routine Permissions.  The log says there is a syntax error however I have checked the syntax and tested it via SQLPro and it runs. We will start out with MYSQL support until we can convert sql to PostgreSQL.

Comment: It says the syntax error is on the first line with the `DELIMITER $$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation Yii handles the `DELIMITER ;;` in the `createCommand()` method. I just had to remove the opening and closing DELIMITER syntax and execute the `Craft::$app->getDb()->createCommand("CREATE PROCEDURE ( ... )")->execute()` for it to install.